# What is the correct way to load a linked page, execute an event, and then unload it in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that allows you to download data from certain sites.

For the past few days, I have attempted to add a feature that will download data from the sites when they are linked from other sites without having to visit the page and click the addon created download button IF the link to the site ends with #ndslink.

I figured out a solution, but it is INCREDIBLY sloppy and I am looking for a better way to implement this.

Here's the behavior:

1. Site A links Site B with an href ending in #nddownload. The link is clicked.
2. The extension disables the default action (open a new window), and instead creates an iframe on Site A and loads the linked URL into the frame.
3. The extension now runs Site B's content script, which specifically looks for #nddownload in the url, and, when found, proceeds to download some data that would normally be downloaded through a manual "Download" button added onto the page via the extension.

Here is my code.

Site B's content script:

```
var decklist = [];
$('.col-name').each(function(i, el) { 
// IRRELEVANT CODE TRIMMMED
    }
});


var data = decklist.join("\r\n");
var saveData = (function () {
// IRRELEVANT CODE TRIMMMED
}());


$(document).ready(function(){
var html = $('.t-deck-title').html();
fileName = $('.t-deck-title').text() + '.txt';
//html = html.replace(/hearthstonedeckdl/, '</br><a class="download" href="#download">DOWNLOAD</a>');
$('.t-deck-title').html(html);
if (window.location.href.indexOf("#ndslink") > -1) {
    saveData(data, fileName);
}
   $(document).on('click', 'a[href="#download"]', function(){
      saveData(data, fileName);
   }); 
});
```

Script loaded on all URLs (incl Site A):

```
var $jg = jQuery.noConflict();
$jg(document).ready(function(){
$jg('a[href$="#ndslink').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});
   $jg(document).on('click', 'a[href$="#ndslink"]', function(){
      //saveData(data, fileName);
      var frameurl = $jg(this).text();
      $jg('body').prepend('<iframe id="nddownload" />');
      $jg("#nddownload").attr("src", frameurl);
      //e.preventDefault();
      // Send link to background and download.
   }); 
});
```

I feel as if I am committing a horrible sin by going this route, but being new to Chrome extensions and generally being inexperienced I could not find a proper way to handle this. I've probably also broken my extension 10 different ways while attempting to do this so a real solution would be much appreciated.

I'm also actually unsure how to go about properly destroying the iframe once the saveData function completes.

Comment: Can you explain why you consider this to be bad?

Comment: Also, please trim your code to a minimal example. Leave out code not relevant to the behavior described.

Comment: Code trimmed. I consider it bad because I figured Chrome has a better way via API to load links and pages and have them be manipulated (via event pages or background pages, maybe?). Adding an iframe into an existing page just seems a little intrusive and evil to me.

Comment: I'm also actually unsure how to go about properly destroying the iframe once the saveData function completes.